# How to define a general function in mathematica?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, expression, definition

How can I define a general function without the exact expression in Mathematica? For example, I don't need this:

```
a[x_, y_]:= 2x + 3y,
```

I need to work with a general parameter a(x,y) instead:

```
a[x_, y_]:= a[x, y].
```

Of course, this line doesn't work too well.

Edit1:

Well, I am using the parameter in another unknown function (unknown because it is defined only in the package), which works basically as a derivative, i.e. it's a very complicated mix of first and second derivatives.

This line

```
a[x_, y_]:= a[x, y],
```

actually works (kind of), because the parameter 'survives' the package as a function, except in the output I get the annoying "`Hold[a[x,y]]`" instead of just `a[x,y]`, and I can't use the result as a function anymore.

Comment: What would be your next step ? What would you do with such a general parameter a(x,y) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to "define" a function without specifying an expression is to *not* define it. Just use it.

Example:

```
D[f[x] g[x],x]
(*
==> g[x] f'[x] + f[x] g'[x]
*)
```

As you can see, I didn't define `f` or `g`, and yet Mathematica has no problems calculating with them.

Note that you can also make definitions using those functions. For example:

```
modify[a[x_,y_]]:=a[y,x+y]
modify[a[2,3]]
(*
==> a[3, 5]
*)
```

You can even define arithmetic operations on them. For example, you could define a function `exp` to symbolically calculate with exponentials (note the lower case, because `Exp` is already the built-in exponential function), and then define

```
exp/: exp[a_] exp[b_] := exp[a+b]
exp/: exp[a_]^n_Integer := exp[n a]
```

and then write

```
expression = 3 exp[x] exp[y+z]^3
(*
==> 3 exp[x + 3 (y + z)]
*)
```